# Accessing Jekyll without port

Tags: apache, jekyll

Is it possible to redirect the base URL to the port in Jekyll? For example I want http://example.com to act as http://example.com:4000. But when I do it via .htaccess, it redirects to :4000. Should I redirect it on Apache configuration and how?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question, but I solved a problem that looks similar to yours:

I have a Jekyll blog running on localhost:4000, which is visible to the outside world as http://example.com/myblog. The address http://example.com was already taken for another website.

The trick is to use mod_proxy in Apache, which is used to serve http://example.com. Apache rewrites any http://example.com/myblog to localhost:4000 and vice versa